# cannot change MySQL character set utf8,once stop/start server ,it stays unchanged

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUo3Q.png)

^ This is my-default.ini.

Even when I log as root, using:
 `set character_set_client = utf8; set character_set_server = utf8;`

Comment: how do you know it's unchanged ?

Comment: use  show variables like ...i have create my.ini file, and it worked. Also, the tag position also need to notice,such as [mysqld]  ,[client]  and so on , the order is important

Answer (score 0):

`my-default.ini` is just a suggestion.  What is in `my.ini`, which is used?

`init-connect` is not seen by `root` (or any other `SUPER` user); do not use `root` for your application; create a separate login.

Also, check via

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

Which needs to have

```
| character_set_client     | utf8
| character_set_connection | utf8
| character_set_results    | utf8
```

(The are not relevant for this question.)

For JDBC, include `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the `getConnection()` call.